# Function "estimate_cdf" not allowing me to select a method, does anyone know why?

Tags: r, statistics, weibull

I am working with a csv file, the file has 2 columns, one of them being a "C1A" which contain all the Time to failure hours and the other "Status", either 0 for censored points and 1 for censored points.

The estimate_cdf function in r studio:
estimate_cdf(x, ...)

```
## S3 method for class 'wt_reliability_data'
estimate_cdf(
  x,
  methods = c("mr", "johnson", "kaplan", "nelson"),
  options = list(),
  ...
).
```

However, whenever i try to select a method, it always returns me a result with the "MR method". How do I get around this?

```
     dataset = read.csv("Test.csv")
     dataset$Failure = as.factor(dataset$Failure)
     dataset$Failure = 1 - as.numeric(dataset$Failure)
     dataset$Failure = 1 + as.numeric(dataset$Failure)
     > dataset


  C1A Failure
1   1027       0
2   3142       1
3   3423       1
4   3323       1
5    531       0
6   3547       0
7   3685       0
8   1122       0
9   1307       0
10   734       0
11  3913       0
12  2429       1
13  3297       1
14  1772       1
15  1148       1
16  2109       0
17   271       1
18  1346       0
19   297       1
20  2775       0
21  2485       1
22  1301       0
23  3360       1
24  1389       0

     estimate_cdf(dataset$C1A, status = dataset$Failure, methods = "johnson")
```

The 'mr' method only considers failed units (status == 1) and does not retain intact units (status == 0).
CDF estimation for method 'mr':

```
# A tibble: 45 x 6
   id        x status  rank   prob cdf_estimation_method
   <chr> <int>  <dbl> <int>  <dbl> <chr>                
 1 ID57    146      1     1 0.0154 mr                   
 2 ID60    147      1     2 0.0374 mr                   
 3 ID86    184      1     3 0.0595 mr                   
 4 ID56    189      1     4 0.0815 mr                   
 5 ID90    203      1     5 0.104  mr                   
 6 ID17    271      1     6 0.126  mr                   
 7 ID19    297      1     7 0.148  mr                   
 8 ID33    322      1     8 0.170  mr                   
 9 ID89    329      1     9 0.192  mr                   
10 ID50    838      1    10 0.214  mr
```

Alternatively,

```
> estimate_cdf(dataset$C1A, status = dataset$Failure, methods = "kaplan")
The 'mr' method only considers failed units (status == 1) and does not retain intact units (status == 0).
CDF estimation for method 'mr':
# A tibble: 45 x 6
   id        x status  rank   prob cdf_estimation_method
   <chr> <int>  <dbl> <int>  <dbl> <chr>                
 1 ID57    146      1     1 0.0154 mr                   
 2 ID60    147      1     2 0.0374 mr                   
 3 ID86    184      1     3 0.0595 mr                   
 4 ID56    189      1     4 0.0815 mr                   
 5 ID90    203      1     5 0.104  mr                   
 6 ID17    271      1     6 0.126  mr                   
 7 ID19    297      1     7 0.148  mr                   
 8 ID33    322      1     8 0.170  mr                   
 9 ID89    329      1     9 0.192  mr                   
10 ID50    838      1    10 0.214  mr
```

It seems that it doesn't matter which method I select, R Studio resorts to "MR" everytime. Does anyone know why?

I've tried to choose from different methods, but it always returns "mr" in the cdf_estimation_method column.

I'm expecting it to change from "mr" to the selected method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming you use the function `estimate_cdf` form the package `weibulltools`. There are actually [multiple functions](https://github.com/Tim-TU/weibulltools/search?l=R&p=2&q=estimate_cdf) being documented with this name.
In your case, you probably want to use the function for which the parameter is called `method` without the plural s at the end.

```
estimate_cdf(dataset$C1A, status = dataset$Failure, method = "johnson")
```

Comment: Thank you so much! When looking at the documentation it seemed that the function required "methods" as an input. The answer you provide worked perfectly, thank you.